# TRIGGERS using HR database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger “Salary_Not_Decrease” to ensure that the salary of an employee is not decreased during update of table Employee.

Please advise on how to start with creating such trigger.

I wrote the following code but not sure about it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Salary_Not_Decrease
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if :new.salary < :old.salary then 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Salary should not be decreased ') ;
end if; 
END;
```

Please advise

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have .. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Your question indicates you want to prevent reductions in salary.  You can't prevent a reduction in salary when there is no salary to reduce, so having this as a before insert trigger doesn't make sense.  Make it just a before update trigger and you should be good to go also as pointed out in the comments you should check for nulls:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Salary_Not_Decrease
BEFORE UPDATE
ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if coalesce(:new.salary,:old.salary-1,0) < nvl(:old.salary,0) then 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Salary should not be decreased ') ;
end if; 
END;
```

Still reading the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) on triggers is a good place to learn more.

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have .. please advise

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new question.

Comment: One comment : take care about handeling NULL values in :new.salary and :old.salary.When one of the components in a comparison is NULL it will always be FALSE, So setting a salary to NULL is allowed. This might be what you want.